# OpenTK texture works only if its not bound

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I don't usually work with low level binds so this might be something silly that I'm overlooking, but I wouldn't know.

When I create a texture from a file like this

```
public Texture ( List<byte> pixels, int width, int height ) {
    handle = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear );
    GL.TexImage2D( TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, width, height, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixels.ToArray() );
}

public void Use () {
    GL.Enable( EnableCap.Texture2D );
    GL.ActiveTexture( TextureUnit.Texture0 );
    GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D, handle );
}
```

And then render it like this:

```
public void Draw () {
    GL.BindVertexArray( VAO );

    //texture.Use();
    shader.Use();

    GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0 );
}
```

Pretty much everything works fine, until I load another texture. ( that makes everything the second texture )
Back to just one texture, when I uncomment `texture.Use();` All My triangles turn black. What is going on?

I checked what values the `GL.GenTexture();` yields, and it's 1 and 2, while the only time the texture renders, the `GL.BindTexture` handle is 0. Setting it to 1 or 2 makes the triangles black.

Comment: `GL.Enable( EnableCap.Texture2D );` is deprecated, its for a compatibility profile context  only. It is useless and superfluous, when using a shader program, but that's not causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GL.GenTexture()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenTextures.xhtml) does not generate a texture, it generates (reserves) a texture (name) id, which can be used to generate a texture object. The texture object is generated when the texture id is bound to a target the first time, by [`GL.BindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml). [`GL.TexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) specify a two-dimensional texture image (it reserves the memory for the image and initializes the image) of an existing texture object. [`GL.TexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) sets parameters to an existing texture object.
That means you have to create the texture object by `GL.BindTexture`, before you can set any texture parameter or specify any texture image:

```cs
public Texture ( List<byte> pixels, int width, int height ) {
    handle = GL.GenTexture();

    GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D, handle ); # <--- THAT IS MISSING

    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest );
    GL.TexParameter( TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear );
    GL.TexImage2D( TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, width, height, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixels.ToArray() );
}
```

Note, the currently bound texture is a global states and that state is kept until it is changed again. `GL.TexImage2D` specifies the texture image of the currently bound texture.
Since the your original function `Texture`, doesn't bind any texture object, `GL.TexImage2D` specifies the texture image of that texture, which is randomly bound to the `Texture2D` target of the current texture unit, at that time.